# How do I convert from int to chars in C++?

Tags: c++

i want transformation from int to char(or string) in c++.

Comment: Try looking into itoa (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/itoa/) ? or stringstreams ?

Comment: I want a beer. Seriously, please show code you have, and what it should look like. Not sure if you want to cast datatypes or format.

Answer (score 8):

Apart from using `stringstream` directly, you can also use [`boost::lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm):

```
std::string x = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(42);
```

Comment: I'd +1 for the most clear C++ solution there is, but I'm out of votes :).

Comment: +.5 for `lexical_cast`; +.5 for `42`.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to convert any basic data type to `char*` is with sprintf:

```
char mystring[MAX_SIZE];
sprintf(mystring, "%d", my_int);
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, that is not specially complex:

```
#include <sstream>

    std::string cnvt(int x)
    {
        std::ostringstream cnvt;

        cnvt << x;

        return cnvt.str();
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Much better than [my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355315/how-do-i-convert-from-int-to-chars-in-c/4355328#4355328), much more C++-y

Comment: Yes, it is more C++, but I've honestly to say that I do prefer yours than mine. :-D

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <sstream>

ostringstream intStream;
int myInt(123456);

intStream << myInt;

string myIntString(intStream.str());
```

Answer (score 0):

Since C++11 you don't need boost, sprintf() or std::ostringstream.
You can simply write:

```
#include <string>

std::string str = std::to_string(1077);
```

or

```
std::wstring wstr = std::to_wstring(1077);
```