# Create char array from int in C

Tags: c

How do you put an int into a char array?

```
int x = 21, i = 3;
char length[4];

while(i >= 0) {
    length[i] = (char) (x % 10);
    x /= 10;
    i--;
} printf("%s\n", length);

// length should now be "0021"
```

The string comes out blank instead.

Note: This is not a duplicate of "How do I convert from int to chars in C++?" because I also need padding. i.e. "0021" not "21"

Comment: what are you trying to do? -> `snprintf(length, sizeof(length), "%d", x);`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert from int to chars in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355315/how-do-i-convert-from-int-to-chars-in-c)

Comment: @MuertoExcobito where is c++?

Comment: @MuertoExcobito This is C, not C++.

Comment: I'm creating a TCP Server/Client and the content I will be sending is structured. ID : 4 Bytes - Version : 6 Bytes - Length : 4 Bytes - Content : Length Bytes. I need to convert the int (x) to a 4 byte char array so I can send it as part of a char array. Example Output: "0001V1.0.00004Text"

Comment: The duplicate may be tagged C++, but it asks about converting int to char, and there is an answer which can be compiled in straight C (using sprint). So, I still think this is a duplicate.

Comment: length[i]=(char)(x%10+48) will work also.

Comment: @MuertoExcobito it will not work that way because sprintf will only put 21 into the char array. I need padding.. 0021 :)

Comment: sprintf(length, "%04d", x); 
Of course, you'll want to increase the size of length, for the null terminator.

Comment: @RussellHickey you can add padding like this `snprintf(length, sizeof(length), "%0*d", numberOfDigits, value);`

Comment: @MuertoExcobito it's better to use `snprintf()` and check it's return value in case the string is too long to fit the destination array, you don't want undefined behavior to happen, do you?

Comment: @iharob Yes, snprintf is safer. However, you still need to increase the size of the char array, otherwise, you don't get the NULL terminator and when you hit the printf, you get 0021#!@$#$#$@!@#$@#$@$!# :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not getting the character code of the digit, you're using the digit as if it were its own character code. It should be:

```
length[i] = '0' + (x % 10);
```

You also need to add an extra element to the `length` array for the terminating null character:

```
char length[5];
length[4] = 0;
```

Comment: Thank You, it worked. I'll accept the answer when allowed. :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `length[4] = '\0';`?

Comment: They're the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your code is basically that `1 != '1'` i.e. the character is not the integer, you need to check the ascii table to see what ascii code represents the character `'1'` but you don't really need to know the number, you can just use `'1'` note the single qoutes.

But you also didn't `nul` terminate your string, you need to add a `'\0'` at the end of the string, so

```
int x = 21, i = 3;
char length[5];

length[4] = '\0';
while (i >= 0) 
{
    length[i--] = x % 10 + '0';
    x          /= 10;
} 
printf("%s\n", length);
```

should work, but is unecessary, you can just

```
snprintf(length, sizeof(length), "%0*d", padding, x);
/*                                         ^ this is how many characters you want */
```

notice that `sizeof` works because `length` is a `char` array, do not confuse that with the length of a string.